# Build iOS app locally without a developer account

Tags: ios, nativescript

I'm just trying out iOS development and no way willing to pay $99 to try out something. I have a running project that works on android and I wanted to see how it looks on iPhone but it seems I'm stuck on all sides.

First of all, I've installed Sidekick and setup Nativescript on the mac and `tns doctor` reports no issues (I originally made the project on Windows with Android phone). Now I'm trying to do a local build but I get an error:

```
[18-10-19 22:49:00.401] Error detected during LiveSync on 9991865793b34ae30366571031b6c251590c222a for /Users/vipulk/Documents/YO. Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/Users/vipulk/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/'
```

I think this is related to certificates and provisioning profiles. I thought you didn't needed those for local builds. Anyways, The sidekick's Auto Generate is of no use either as [it doesn't work with 2FA accounts](https://github.com/NativeScript/sidekick-feedback/issues/110).

I tried to use [this guide](https://docs.nativescript.org/sidekick/user-guide/code-signing/code-signing-for-ios/code-signing-assistance) to create these files manually. I created the csr file but step 6 asks you to go to [this page](https://docs.nativescript.org/sidekick/user-guide/code-signing/code-signing-for-ios/create-development-certificate) which asks you to use your development program. Again, don't have that.

The cloud build also needs certificates.

What do I do?

Comment: You can absolutely try out Xcode to develop on simulator and phone without a paid developer membership. (I don't know anything about Sidekicks etc. so can't comment on that. What I know about is that you just use Xcode directly.) But there are limitations, naturally.

Comment: you don't have to buy paid account for development you can create free account and use it.

Comment: I do have a free account but I don't know how to get certificates with that account or if I even need it. I've posted this question here because this is the official place for Nativescript support now and I'm hoping a Nativescript staff member will be able to shed some light on this topic.

Comment: If you try to launch the app from the generated Xcode project (assuming you have logged in to [free] developer account in Xcode) the system will automatically create keys and allows you to run the app directly on device. But remember, the package name should be unique otherwise it may fail. Also it won't support features like Push notification, in app purchases etc., those are available only for paid accounts.

Comment: Guys thanks for your replies but this is a nativescript specific question. I'm not using xcode.

Answer (score 0):

The [NativeScript](https://www.nativescript.org/get-the-nativescript-book) Book has two chapters at the end on iOS deployment, and they address your question, though they don't use sidekick.  But, hey, nothing wrong with the good old {N} CLI.